# using xlswrite inside a loop and an error when using mac

Tags: matlab

I am trying to use the xlswrite inside a loop to put the results in each iteration

my function is like this

```
xlswrite('results',results(1,i).A,'results',data);
```

I get the following errors,

```
Error using xlswrite (line 187)
An error occurred on data export in CSV format.

Error in myalgorithm (line 178)
    xlswrite('results',results(1,i).A,'results',data);


Caused by:
    Error using dlmwrite (line 112)
    The input cell array cannot be converted to a matrix.
```

I am using Matlab 2015b and also I am using mac
I also tried to use csvwrite  instead xlswrite but no success. is there any one who can help me with it?

Comment: You cannot use xlswrite on a Mac, they do not have Microsoft's COM. You cannot use csvwrite or dlmread unless your data is strictly numeric. Use fprintf.

Comment: @excaza can you please show an example that you use fprintf as an answer, I will accept it